# How can I separate the SQL results using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've created a query which returns the results below. Is there a way to split up these results by `object_id` after the results are returned? I've tried grouping by the `object_id` in SQL but only the results from object id: `212` is returned.

I simply need to group these results to be displayed using PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: SQL results]

Here is my PHP code containing the query:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value
    FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    WHERE $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    IN (107, 108)
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key
    LIKE 'c%'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value != ''";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>

<?php if ($pageposts): ?>
    <?php global $post; ?>
    <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
        <?php print_r($post->object_id); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    error
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sort by `order_id` and then in php check if `order_id` of a current row differs from previous.

Comment: Show the code which you tried

Comment: There is also `GROUP_CONCAT` in mysql this has a [decent example](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) that you could use together with `GROUP BY` that would return a list of values sperated by a character that can easily be [exploded](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) if you want an array.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions. @JennevanderMeer - I'll give the `GROUP_CONCAT` a go and let you know if I get it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate all of your swift responses. Thanks to @JenneVanDerMeer I managed to return the grouped values by applying `GROUP_CONCAT` to the `meta_value` and `GROUP BY` to the `object_id`. The working query is below:

```
SELECT wp_term_relationships.object_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(wp_postmeta.meta_value), wp_postmeta.meta_key
FROM wp_term_relationships 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = 
wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN (107)
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key
LIKE 'c%'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != ''  
GROUP BY wp_term_relationships.object_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ORDER BY` would work just fine here.

`SELECT object_id, meta_value FROM <TABLE> ORDER BY object_id ASC`

Comment: This would be exactly like the image he posted, and wasn't really the question at hand. Granted it wasn't the most clearest of all questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @Dan. But using `ORDER BY` only sorts the data and doesn't group them.

Comment: What do you mean by "group" then? I guess I am not understanding the expected result.

Comment: I essentially wanted to group the results based on the `object_id` as the results returned was just a list. I've written the answer on this page and it turned out I needed to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` clause (suggested by Jenne). Thanks again for your help!